# Recover old files in 14.04

Tags: 13.04, files, 14.04, data-recovery

I recently made a mistake of upgrading to LTS 14.04, only to find out that my Athlon LE1660 and 2GB RAM was not able to support this OS. So I made bootable copy of Ubuntu 13.04 on an flash drive and reinstall 13.04 and also to try and recover some files but I don;t know how to do this as I no longer can access my old file in 14.04. When I try to boot up using 14.04 it just freezes each time. When I try to access the the files from 13.04 it gives me an error message saying I don't have the proper permissions.

Comment: Welcome to AU! Please define the issue that you have corrected so we don't waste time that could be spentt helping on something that is already solved. Better yet, post it as an answer to help others! Thank you

Comment: Did you try the 32-bit version of 14.04?

Comment: Athlon LE1660 is 64-bit and only 5 years old, it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed the 13.04 over your old system, then your files will most likely **be lost**.

But if you installed it along the other, you can try the following:

I'm assuming that you know a bit about disks and mounting. I'm also assuming that your old system was on partition 2 of `sda` and your new system is on partition 3.

If it is like this, you can simply try mounting the old system:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
```

If this doesn't work or you weren't using the recommended filesystem or whatever, you either need to specify the filesystem (like `sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt -t ntfs`) or it gives an error, which we need to know in order to help you.

"I don't have proper permissions" is very very vague.

Comment: Yes, I reinstalled along the other 14.04. In fact I can see it (the disk where my files are) on the launcher. bar I tried "sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt" and got result "mount: block device /dev/sda2 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: you must specify the filesystem type"

Comment: What does `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda` prints out? It might be **not** sda **2**, that's just an example. you'd have to take the partition on which your old system was.

Comment: Sorry been away from my PC for a while to do gardening. I tried sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda and it printout
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   431393383   215695668   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       431394814   625141759    96873473    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       621473792   625141759     1833984   82  Linux swap / Solaris/dev/sda6       522663936   617803775    47569920   83  Linux/dev/sda7  617805824   621459455     1826816   82  Linux swap / Solaris/dev/sda8 431394816   522661887  45633536 83 Linux
Partition table entries are not in disk order

Comment: It seems like you have 3 partitions where there might be data.
Try to mount partition 6 or 8 to see, if the data you're looking for might be there, or if you even might be able to mount it.

`sudo mount /dev/sda6 /mnt`
or
`sudo mount /dev/sda8 /mnt`

If one of these commands work, you should be able to see the folder tree under /mnt.

If you never used the terminal before, this article might help: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal

Comment: I did as suggested. partition 6 and 8 are already on the launch bar but when I try to access my data, I get the error message,"This location could not be displayed. You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of “disk”."

Comment: Are you root when you try to access the path?
If you're in terminal and you change as root to the mounted folder and make an `ls -la` - What does it display?

Answer (score 0):

After mounting the partitions, try `gksu nautilus` to open the file manager with root permissions, navigate to your mount points and find your files there. If that doesn't work, seek answers regarding data recovery. There are some good ones here.