# "Your current Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE) is no longer supported"

Tags: 14.04, hardware-enablement-stack

So my ubuntu wont start after updates in graphics mode and this is what I get in prompt;

```
Your current Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE) is no longer supported since 2014-08-07. 
Security updates for critical parts (kernel and graphcis stack) of your system are no
longer available. For more information, please see: http://wiki.ubuntu.com/1204_HWE_EOL

There is a graphics stack installed on this system. An upgrade to a supporter (or
longer supported) configuration will become available on 2014-07-16 and can be invoked 
by running 'update-manager in the Dash
```

I would want to recover the pictures and music from HDD, how I do that? Is there any chance to roll back previous version of Ubuntu to get it back in graphics mode?

Comment: Do you still have, or can you create a live disk? If so you can boot using the live disk, copy your data to another location, then install a supported version (12.04 or 14.04).

Comment: Yes I have tried that and I can see my files but I cant copy them because "Im not the owner"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that by following this question; [Recover old files in 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453666/recover-old-files-in-14-04) I finally had access my files and at the moment backing my files. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you still have the installation usb drive with storage for use with the live media... One piece of advice I can give... Issues like this are why I refuse to use only one partition like Ubuntu wants me to. I always set an 11 gig for root partition(`/`), then I make a `/home` partition taking up all the rest of the room except for what I want the `swap` to be, which I then setup as my third partition... all primary... no logical partitions. Then I can reinstall and everything will still be there for me in my home directory.

However, for now from the prompt try and run:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-update
```

the first part will check for new packages on the repository and the second half will upgrade all packages that are available for upgrade. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what your updates were, maybe you should try to remove all the packages you installed since last time your GUI was functioning.

I had this problem when I was trying to configure my nvidia driver. I installed `nvidia-prime` and `ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa`. Then after a reboot I came across exactly the same problem, and I uninstalled both using these commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-prime
sudo ppa-purge xorg-edgers
```

It worked and after a reboot I was able to open the system normally with graphics display.